# Saving to a File or local database with Serilog, which is better or faster?

Tags: serilog, .net-core-3.1

For SeriLog Sinks
We are just wondering for the sake of a good performance we have the following questions:
1-  Is logging to files much better or faster than saving to a local database!?
2-  There shouldn’t be  any issue with saving files to a shared network location, but please advise if

Answer (score 2):

As with everything, *it depends*. Sure, you could generally expect that writing to a text file is a less expensive operation than writing to a database, especially if the file is being written locally and the database is remote, but you won't know for sure until you measure it and see if the difference in performance is meaningful to you/your users.

Who knows? Maybe your disk is slow, or the latency to write in the network share is worst than the latency to write to the database.

If this is an important thing for you/your project (i.e. performance is critical), then measure it and decide based on the results.

Also, your perception of performance will differ if you are sending the logs synchronously or asynchronously, and if send them in batches, or one by one.

So again, measure it...

Check the configuration options available in your text & database sink (e.g. `batchPostingLimit`, `period`), and take a look at the [`Serilog.Sinks.Async`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async) which allows you to delegate the logging to a background thread if needed.

---

Of course, if performance is not critical at this stage, it's very easy to change the Serilog configuration later anyway, so you can always start with whatever you prefer, and switch to a different sink/combination of sinks at a later time...